# ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::CorruptException: database disk image is malformed: SELECT "packages".* FROM "packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I got this error in every part of my rails app. The solution recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417781/getting-sqlite3corruptexception-database-disk-image-is-malformed-from-rails)  question is good when the data is not important to lose.But my problem is I need the data and I don't know how to fix this error.please help.

Comment: My development.sqlite3 is malformed and I can not repair it .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your sqlite file is broken.
Try it:
`sqlite3 prodcution.db "PRAGMA integrity_check;"`
[Pragma statements supported by SQLite](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check)
　
Once you backup and rebuild db, it may work.
`sqlite3 prodcution.db ".dump" | sqlite3 prodcution.db.new`

Comment: my db is development.sqlit3 is integrity check possible for this db ?

Comment: Yes. Try `integrity_check `.

Comment: I followed this: http://froebe.net/blog/2015/05/27/error-sqlite-database-is-malformed-solved/  to recover the missed data but I couldn't instead I used development log to track the lost data.

Comment: Did not it work out the way I introduced , dump and rebuild?

Comment: I did but still I lost some data in the dump file. I used the log file to find the missed data.